# What causes a Login Error One Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

Please take a look at the following code this is for the front end of my website going through wordpress without having the wordpress platform being used, however the login page is having issues.

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;

    $err = '';
    $success = '';

    if(isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] == 'login' )
    {
        //We shall SQL escape all inputs to avoid sql injection.
        $username = $wpdb->escape($_POST['log']);
        $password = $wpdb->escape($_POST['pwd']);
        $remember = $wpdb->escape($_POST['remember']);


        if( $username == "" || $password == "" ) {
            $err = 'Please don\'t leave the required field.';
        } else {
            $user_data = array();
            $user_data['user_login'] = $username;
            $user_data['user_password'] = $password;
            $user_data['remember'] = $remember;  
            $user = wp_signon( $user_data, false );

            if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
                $err = $user->get_error_message();
                exit();
            } else {
                wp_set_current_user( $user->ID, $username );
                do_action('set_current_user');

                echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location='. get_bloginfo('url') .'</script>';  
                exit(); 
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

This is the form been used for the login.

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="message"><h2>Already have an account? Please login.</h2></div>
    <p>
    <?php 
        if( !empty($sucess) ) 
            echo $sucess;

        if( !empty($err) )
            echo $err;
        ?>
    </p>
        <input type="text" name="log" value="" id="log" class="textbox" placeholder="Username"/>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" value="" id="pwd" class="textbox" placeholder="Password"/>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Login" class="button" />

    <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="true" /> Remember Me</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="login" />
</form>
```

Why am i getting the following: Warning can not modify header information

How do i get around this?

Comment: Please delete your cookies and cache and try it again.

Comment: Have you tried to enable debug mode to see if there are more details about the error? Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress